# How to give more than 1 input parameter in epicbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I'm trying to use [epicbox](https://github.com/StepicOrg/epicbox) to run a python code. I'm facing two problems.
This is my code:

```
import epicbox
import pprint

untrusted_code = b"""
a = input()
print(a)
b = input()
print(b)"""

epicbox.configure(
    profiles=[
        epicbox.Profile('python', 'python')
    ]
)
files = [{'name': 'main.py', 'content': untrusted_code}]
limits = {'cputime': 1, 'memory': 64}
result = epicbox.run('python', 'python main.py', files=files, limits=limits, stdin="12 19")
pprint.pprint(result)
```

First I'm not sure how to put more than 1 input parameter in stdin, and secondly, it gives me the following error in the output:

```
{
 'duration': 0.098507,
 'exit_code': 1,
 'oom_killed': False,
 'stderr': b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/sandbox/main.py", li'
           b'ne 4, in <module>\n    b = input()\nEOFError: EOF when reading a l'
           b'ine\n',
 'stdout': b'12 19\n',
 'timeout': False
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
I need to put `\n` between the parameters in stdin:

```
epicbox.run('python', 'python main.py', files=files, limits=limits, stdin='12\n13')
```

Comment: now you can accept your answer and upvote it.